# playing an audio file in Qt 4.4 in windows XP

Tags: c++, qt4

I tried to play a audio file in Qt 4.4 in windows XP using phonon classes (MediaObject,MediaSource,AudioOutput). The code gets compiled and ran but the audio file is not playing. I enabled the phonon support  and setup the backend as well. Someone can please help me with this. i attached my code also for reference. Also i dont want to use QDesktopServices and all.

```
Phonon::AudioOutput *audioOutput=new Phonon::AudioOutput(Phonon::MusicCategory,this);
Phonon::MediaObject *mediaObject=new Phonon::MediaObject(this);
mediaObject->setTickInterval(1000);
Phonon::createPath(mediaObject,audioOutput);
Phonon::MediaSource source("D:\\CAT\\audioFile.mp3");
mediaObject->setCurrentSource(source);
mediaObject->play();
```

Answer (score 0):

your code seem to be fine; what you might want to check if your backend (I guess DirectShow if you're running windows) has needed audio device available or/and the audio format is supported by backend. In order to do this you can use functions from Phonon [BackendCapabilities](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.4/phonon-backendcapabilities.html) namespace. As an alternative you can build and run an example application which comes with QT, it should be in your_qt_folder/examples/phonon/capabilities

[alt text http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.4/images/capabilitiesexample.png](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.4/images/capabilitiesexample.png)

more details regarding this example here: [Capabilities Example](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.4/phonon-capabilities.html)

I guess if it doesn't show you anything then you need to check your backend installation or your audio device or\and format are not supported